# How to properly insert a datetime in Oracle database?

Tags: php, oracle

I am inserting date in my Oracle database, the problem is I cannot insert a date.

Here is my code:

```
$clientquery = "INSERT INTO TBLCLIENT(CLIENTSID, NAME, BORWTYP, CLIENTTP, CLIENTUPDATE) VALUES('". $cid ."', '". $fullname ."', 'IND', 'I', '". $client_update ."')";
$clientsql = oci_parse($conn, $clientquery);
$clientexec = oci_execute($clientsql);
```

Here is the sample query:

> INSERT INTO LCCLIENT(CLIENTID, NAME, BORWTP, CLIENTTP, CLIENTUPDATE) VALUES('2000050431', 'hshs, js hdh', 'IND', 'I', '23-Sep-2019 02:11:48')

I am getting this error when I tried to insert a data:

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a date in to_date function to convert string to oracle recognizable date as follows:

```
INSERT INTO LCCLIENT(CLIENTID, NAME, BORWTP, CLIENTTP, CLIENTUPDATE) 
VALUES('2000050431', 'hshs, js hdh', 'IND', 'I', 
      to_date('23-Sep-2019 02:11:48','dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi:ss')); <-- this
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks it works, but can you tell me why that works? Oracle is very different to mysql or mssql when inserting a date

Comment: Yes, In oracle You need to specify the format of the date with to_date function or else it will consider NLS_DATE_FORMAT as default format and accepts date in that format only.